# Metal Vertex Shader Warning in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal, vertex-shader

I got this passthrough vertex shader I used from Apple's sample code:

```
vertex VertexIO vertexPassThrough(device packed_float4 *pPosition  [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                  device packed_float2 *pTexCoords [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                  uint                  vid        [[ vertex_id ]])
{
    VertexIO outVertex;

    outVertex.position = pPosition[vid];
    outVertex.textureCoord = pTexCoords[vid];

    return outVertex;
}
```

This worked in Swift 4/Xcode 10/iOS 12.  Now I with Swift 5/Xcode 11/iOS 13, I get this warning:

```
writable resources in non-void vertex function
```

Comment: Try `const device ...` for those buffers.

Comment: perfect! Warning went away!  Please post this as an answer so I can mark.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to ensure the shader can only read from those buffers, so you need to change the declaration to `const device`:

```
vertex VertexIO vertexPassThrough(const device packed_float4 *pPosition  [[ buffer(0) ]],
                                  const device packed_float2 *pTexCoords [[ buffer(1) ]],
                                  uint                  vid        [[ vertex_id ]])
{
...
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why we need to insure read-only access to those buffers? What's the reason behind it? I'm new to this and trying to understand the basic concepts. I also think it would make your answer better. Thanks!

Comment: @alobaili Graphics APIs, in general, are very interested whether the CPU and/or GPU can read/write buffers so it knows where to allocate those buffers.  The use of `const` reinforces the notion that the GPU only wants read access to these buffers.